# Facebook Open Graph: Can't Download - Could not retrieve data from URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-headers, facebook-opengraph

Everything was working fine when suddenly I started to get this Open Graph error on all pages:

http://n-pix.com

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fn-pix.com%2F

I've tried many suggestions from other questions, but nothing worked yet.

And if I save the static HTML from the page and load it on Open Graph debugger, everything works perfectly:

http://n-pix.com/ogtest.html

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fn-pix.com%2Fogtest.html

Any suggestions? Maybe something wrong with the headers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've  found the problem:

PHP GZIP compression was causing the problem. As soon I disabled it, the problem was solved and this explain the different behavior between dynamic and static pages.

I hope this can help more people in the future.

Comment: Disabling GZIP worked out for me too, but that's definitely not a solution. We've disabled it in recette environment, but we can't do something like that for the production environment... Maybe disabling GZIP for `.html` pages only would do the trick? (we've disabled it totally, for all elements). What approach would you recommend?

Comment: Disabling PHP GZIP will disable compression only for the html that php outputs. Compression of html, css, js and other files is faster and more reliable when handled by the webserver (nginx or apache) and Facebook Opengraph has no issues in this case.