# Facebook open graph: Could not retrieve data from URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to share this site on Facebook but, FB did not recognize the og tags in the page.
The page url is: http://miriwein.com/
I was checked in the "Open Graph Object Debugger" and I have got this error:

```
Errors That Must Be Fixed
Can't Download  Could not retrieve data from URL.
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.miriwein.com
Someone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

SO, as I found here: [Facebook Open Graph: Can't Download - Could not retrieve data from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197151/facebook-open-graph-cant-download-could-not-retrieve-data-from-url) Just disable GZip compression & problem solved.